# Preview text with subject in subject line

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, email, amazon-s3, html-email

I want to show preview text with subject in subject line not the body of the email. before this I'm showing body f the email with the subject in subject line.I'm using the Golang AWS SES-v2 https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sesv2  package for sending emails

Before It seems like
https://nimb.ws/N5E9XC8

But Now I want to show a preview text in place of body with the subject in subject line like
https://nimb.ws/EHuPjG6

Comment: First show your work please

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of pre header that gets used in emails. The code goes right after the body tag of an email (before the contents of the email).

```html
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#333333;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden">Pre header text goes here
&#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; &#8199;&#65279;&#847; </div>
```